# Array controls XML delievy AS3

Tags: arrays, xml, actionscript-3, flash

So, let's say I have an Array on Flash, something like:

```
var myArray:Array = [option2, option3]
```

and let's also say I have a XML file something like this:

```
<easFormat>
    <option1>
         <easimg>img01.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 01</easName>
         <easPrice>250.000</easPrice>
    </option1>
    <option2>
         <easimg>img02.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 02</easName>
         <easPrice>180.000</easPrice>
    </option2>
    <option3>
         <easimg>img03.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 03</easName>
         <easPrice>80.000</easPrice>
    </option3>
    <option4>
         <easimg>img04.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 04</easName>
         <easPrice>150.000</easPrice>
    </option4>
</easFormat>
```

I already have my XML properly loaded.
Now I want to display only the nodes of my XML that match the array values  (options 2 and 3). Could you guys help me to sort out the logic for doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should change the xml structure as follows

```
<easFormat>
    <option>
         <easimg>img01.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 01</easName>
         <easPrice>250.000</easPrice>
    </option>
    <option>
         <easimg>img02.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 02</easName>
         <easPrice>180.000</easPrice>
    </option>
    <option>
         <easimg>img03.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 03</easName>
         <easPrice>80.000</easPrice>
    </option>
    <option>
         <easimg>img04.jpg</easimg>
         <easName>Carro 04</easName>
         <easPrice>150.000</easPrice>
    </option>
</easFormat>
```

and assume your search options are

```
var options:Array = ["Carro 01", "Carro 04"];
```

Now the code for onloaded xml

```
var _xml:XML = XML(e.target.data);
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < _xml.option.length(); i++){
        easNames.push(_xml.option[i].easName);
    }
```

Checking weather the options in the easNames array.

```
function matchTest():void{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        for(var j:uint = 0; j < easNames.length; j++){
            if(easNames[j] == options[i]){
                trace(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```